# How to reduce memory usage in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I am trying to open a csv file and go through a specific column that contains user reviews for games. I am then opening another file with a list of words, and I am adding a column to the original csv file for every word that is contained in the second file, and the number of times that word is found in the user review. The original csv file has about 25 million rows, and is 7.2gb in size. I am running out of memory fairly quickly when trying to run this script. I am using chunking, and am splitting the file into 100,000 rows at a time. How can I further reduce memory usage? I'm certain my code is not very efficient. Here is my code:

```
import pandas as pd

df_chunk = pd.read_csv("all_comments_data.csv", chunksize=100000)

df = pd.DataFrame()

for chunk in df_chunk:

    words = open("conflict_words.txt")
    words = words.readlines()
    list_of_words = []

    main_dict = {}

    for word in words:
        list_of_words.append(word.strip())
        main_dict[word.strip()] = 0

    dictionary_per_row = main_dict

    list_of_dicts = []

    for row in chunk.itertuples():
        dictionary_per_row = main_dict.copy()
        for word in list_of_words:
            if word in row[5]:
                dictionary_per_row[word] += 1
        list_of_dicts.append(dictionary_per_row)

    df_to_append = pd.DataFrame(list_of_dicts)
    df = pd.concat([df, df_to_append], ignore_index=True)


df.to_csv("/home/user/Desktop/scripts/all_comments_data_with_conflict_scores.csv")
```

How can I optimize this code?

Comment: You code is not reproducible, so it's difficult to answer...